# Set the parent of Usercontrol in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to achieve navigation like layout using UserControl created by user.

I have a Silverlight Page that loads Usercontrol by setting the Content to a Frame Element.

```
UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
this.Frame.Content = uc1;
```

Similarly I have a Frame in each UserControl  where the content is set to a Frame.

This works well and good.

**Problem:**
I have the current situation

|UserControl1 | UserControl2 | UserControl3  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
UserControl1 |                       |      CHILD            |
UserControl2 | PARENT            |                       |CHILD 
UserControl3 |                        |PARENT         |

So now what I'm trying to achieve is that when the user opens UserControl2 from UserControl1, i need to be able to move back from UserControl2 to the parent(UserControl1) **in the same state it was before**.

Is this actually possible? If yes then what should be done?
Any Hints, code, Article references are appreciated...

**Reason:**

I'm trying to avoid passing variables in page query and use usercontrols.

**Scenario:**

For instance if the user wrote "Hello World" in a Textbox inside UserControl1 and presses a button,load  UserControl2. After he presses OK in UserControl2 go back to UserControl1 with the Textbox still showing "Hello World"

Hope I'm clear. Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but your controls should not be UserControls, but instead inherit from [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page%28v=vs.95%29) and you should use the Navigate method of the Frame to set the first page

```
this.Frame.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then to navigate from page 1 to page 2 use the [NavigationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationservice%28v=vs.95%29) of the Page

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: I'm already doin that now. I'm tryin to move away from that and use UserControl instead of Page.

Comment: Why go away from this? It accomplishes keeping state like you want. You can do this, but you then have to manage the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might do it:

```
List<UserControl> navigationStack = new List<UserControl>();

public void NavigateTo(UserControl newUC)
{
  // when navigating to a new control, keep the old one in memory
  if (this.Frame.Content != null) 
    navigationStack.Add(this.Frame.Content as UserControl);
  this.Frame.Content = newUC;
}

public void NavigateBack()
{
  // when navigating back to an old control in memory, 
  // retrieve it off the navigation stack
  UserControl oldUC = navigationStack.LastOrDefault();
  if (oldUC != null)
  {  
     navigationStack.Remove(oldUC);
     this.Frame.Content = oldUC;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'll try it. The pattern already is look promising from the looks of it.:-)